# Не работает декоратор метода класса

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, декоратор

Пока я использую декоратор без `@`, всё вызывается и работает, но когда я пытаюсь вызвать декоратор через `@`, декоратор не находит декорируемую функцию. Использовать декоратор без "собачки" можно, но неудобно. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем здесь дело? Заранее благодарен!

```
import time


class Cls:
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        print(f'constructor -> "{file_name}"')  # .....

    def chronometer(self, func):  # Метод-Декоратор
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print(f'{func.__name__} - started')
            func(*args, **kwargs)
            print(f'{func.__name__} - finished')

        return wrapper

    @chronometer                    # (Не могу ПРИДЕЛАТЬ декоратор через собачку-@)
    def decorated_fun(self):  # декорируемый Метод
        for i in range(5):
            print(f'  ***** ({i})')  # .....
            time.sleep(0.2)

    def apply(self):  # Метод применения Декоратора
        # --------------------------------------------------------------------------
        # # Вариант 1: - (без собачки-@)  # (РАБОТАЕТ!)
        # self.chronometer(self.decorated_fun)()
        # --------------------------------------------------------------------------
        # # Вариант 2: - (без собачки-@)  # (РАБОТАЕТ!)
        # self.decorated_fun = self.chronometer(self.decorated_fun)
        # self.decorated_fun()
        # --------------------------------------------------------------------------
        # Вариант 3: - (с собачкой-@)  # (НЕ РАБОТАЕТ!)
        self.decorated_fun()
        # --------------------------------------------------------------------------
        pass


# обращение:
cls = Cls('aquarius.dat')
cls.apply()

# Вывод:
# constructor -> "aquarius.dat"
# decorated - started
#   ***** (0)
#   ***** (1)
#   ***** (2)
#   ***** (3)
#   ***** (4)
# decorated - finished
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: - Пока я использую декоратор без-@, все вызывается и работает, но когда я пытаюсь вызвать декоратор через-@, декоратор не находит декорируемую функцию. Использовать декоратор без собачки можно, но неудобно. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем здесь дело? Заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно переделать декоратор, `self` убрать во `wrapper`:

```py
    def chronometer(func):  # Метод-Декоратор
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print(f'{func.__name__} - started')
            func(self, *args, **kwargs)
            print(f'{func.__name__} - finished')
        return wrapper
```

Рецепт подсмотрен на [английском СО](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38524579/8324991).

Но вообще так лучше не делать, как написано там же. Декораторы лучше не помещать в классы.

Comment: - Спасибо Вам CrazyElf. Действительно все заработало и заработало правильно! Правда PyCharm подсвечивает все подряд. А что же делать, если возникает необходимость декорировать Метод класса?  Как делать это ПРАВИЛЬНО?

Comment: @staut Посмотрите другие ответы по приведённой мной ссылке на английский СО, возможно там что-то подходящее найдётся. По крайней мере сам декоратор всё же лучше выносить из класса.

Comment: - Да, да, спасибо огромное за ссылку CrazyElf! Как раз читал ее. Действительно очень интересная статья. Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: @staut я своим ученикам рекомендую изучать азы Python и синтаксиса по [Sololearn](https://www.sololearn.com/learning/1073), к чему я это это. При поиске того, что такое декораторы просто гугля можно сильно запутаться, но обратите внимание, в данном бесплатном курсе декораторы отнесены к блоку **functional programming**, который идёт до **ООП**, иначе говоря декораторы к классам не относятся.

Comment: - Спасибо DiMithras за полезную информацию. Я знаю, что декоратор (паттерн программирования) более ранняя вещь, чем ООП. Но ведь сейчас есть и Декораторы-Классы и Декораторы-Классов ... Как то все это уживается! Значит нужно учиться пользоваться.